# Dynamically Organizing Streamed Data in Web UI Based on Partial Metadata

Tags: user-interface, dynamic, streaming

I'm streaming data from a GPT endpoint into a web application and need to dynamically place each item into specific UI elements based on keys received with the data. The challenge is the metadata (indicating UI placement) arrives partially at the start of the stream.

**Example Scenario:**
I receive data objects like `{ id: "uniqueKey1", content: "Example text"}`. As you can see, I can only determine where `content` goes based on `id`.

**Question:**
What are efficient strategies or tools for dynamically updating the UI with streamed data, especially when the placement metadata is initially incomplete? Any lightweight example or pseudocode for dynamically inserting text into a table based on late-arriving metadata would be helpful.